# Is it possible to chain multiple (more than 2) CouchDB nodes using replicate

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to replicate multiple nodes of Couch DB by using replicate? In GUI / fauxton to set up replication, there is a local and remote.    can you keep say 4 instances of couch DB in sync across 4 separate datasite locations?

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, you'll need to set up multiple replications. "Chaining" as a concept does not exist.